# Find the subsets of a to b numbers that sum to a value between p and q

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a set of n numbers, find the subsets of a to b numbers that sum to a value between p and q.

For example:

Input: S = {2, 3, 4, 5}, a = 2, b = 3, p = 3, q= 9

Output: { {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {2, 3, 4} }

I know this problem can be solved using backtracking, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: What have done on your own? Please also mention your efforts to solve the problem as well.

Comment: Are the n numbers all different? Is it possible to have repetition? And as @AKSingh said, you should mention your efforts to solve the problem